# Can I create a wrapper around NUnit, MbUnit, xUnit or other testing framework?

Tags: nunit, mstest, wrapper, mbunit, xunit

How can I create a wrapper around a testing framework? We still doesn't know which testing framework are going to use, but I need to start writing unit tests. With this question I want to know how can I switch from NUnit to mbUnit, xUnit or even MSTest.

Comment: why would you want to do that? You can decide which one suits your need well & go for the one that fits the bill.

Comment: The thing is that the customer is still defining the requirements for the code. This is an outsourced development. And one of the things that are pending is the test framework that the customer will use. But we need to start coding immediately to start with our sprint process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a wrapper - but I think you can utilise your time much better. I'd say pick the simplest one (My personal favourite would be the war-horse NUnit) that fits your needs - the newer frameworks add functionality that help you write more complex test fixtures.
However I value simplicity over "flexibility". In the future, if you find yourself wanting that "cool feature X in Y testing framework", you could either write that particular test fixture using Y. (you could also migrate the entire test fixture to use Y for consistency - but time is always scarce) - Switch between 2 unit testing framework is usually monotonous work (rename attributes) however [some might be more work](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/gunit.aspx) (disclaimer: no flying time with MbUnit)

Your comment however worries me a bit.

1. Why is the customer deciding the testing framework that you'd use for development - it should be a choice of the development team. The customer wouldn't want you to define product requirements - would he/she ? The quality of tests doesn't depend on the framework used so I don't see how this affects the customer.

Comment: Well, believe me, it's hard to answer that question. But let's say the IT consultant for our customer whats to sound very "showy". I agree, we need simplicity over flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an existing wrapper that allows you to run multiple unit test frameworks, so even if you switch frameworks you can still use the old unit tests. For the unit test frameworks you listed, I would recommend taking a look at Gallio.

From http://www.gallio.org/...

> At present Gallio can run tests from MbUnit versions 2 and 3, MSTest, NBehave, NUnit, xUnit.Net, csUnit, and RSpec.  Gallio provides tool support and integration with AutoCAD, CCNet, MSBuild, NAnt, NCover, Pex, Powershell, Resharper, TestDriven.Net, TypeMock, and Visual Studio Team System.